# Django Login Form Displaying Incorrectly

Tags: django, django-forms

My basic login page works fine when I go through the login link directly. It correctly applies the class 'form-control' to the input. The strange issue arrives if I try to visit a page that I need to be logged in for to view, it will redirect to the login page(as expected) but then for some reason it decides to not apply my attributes to the form. I am unsure as to why this is happening, maybe due to the redirect to the page instead of an actual visitation. I've attached screen shots to show exactly what I mean. When inspecting the html I can clearly see the attributes are not applying when it seems to be a redirect to the login page. Why does it behave in this way? What would be the best way to fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

basic view for the login page

```
class MyAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['username'].widget = forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
        self.fields['password'].widget = forms.widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
```

login template as requested:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block css_files  %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'login-out.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid" id='loginout'>
{% if next %}
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
    please login with an account that has access.</p>
  {% else %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<section id="form-test">
<div class="container w-25 pt-3">
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
          {{ form.username.label_tag }}
          {{ form.username }}
          {{ form.password.label_tag }}
          {{ form.password }}
          {{ form.non_field_errors }}
      </div>
      <input class='btn btn-outline-primary' type="submit" value="Login" />
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
  </form>
  
  
  <p><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Lost password?</a></p>
</div>
</section>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

login view as requested:

```
class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        messages.success(self.request, f'Welcome {self.request.user}')
        return response
```

[image: correctly displayed form with attributes] [image: incorrectly displayed form without attributes]

Comment: How do you redirect to the login page, can you share that logic?

Comment: You might want to use something like django-crispy-forms to style your forms on display instead of having to subclass and modify them in the code.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem honestly no I cannot, I believe that happens behind the scenes with Django. I never purposely setup that redirect in my log as far as I am aware haha. It may be something with LoginMixin's but I am not entirely sure

Comment: @AKX thank you for the suggestion, if need be I can easily change to crispy forms I just prefer to do things this way for my own knowledge:). I'm sure that would work but I want to try and solve it without using anything

Comment: Can you share the login page template?

Comment: @Demetris yes, added to original post

Comment: How do you override the `form_class` with `MyAuthenticationForm`?

Comment: @Demetris sorry i'm still relatively new to Django so I am not sure what you're asking. I think maybe you're asking how I pass the form? I pass it in the main urls for my project like so path('accounts/login', MyLoginView.as_view(authentication_form=MyAuthenticationForm), name='login')

Comment: Thanks. Can't see anything wrong to be honest. Does the HTML render correctly on the browser? Inspect the HTML of the form in the two screenshots above; is the second one missing the `form-control` class?

Comment: @Demetris haha exactly why I am confused as well. it's really strange behavior, technically I can just raise a 403 error instead of just using the RequiredLoginMixin default redirect behavior but I don't want to do that as I feel it is inconvenient for users. Yes exactly, in the HTML in the second screen shot it's missing the form-control class, so the attributes aren't being applied. I truly think it's some behavior due to being redirected to the page instead of a regular request

Comment: oh wait, you have a custom login view `MyLoginView`. Post that as well.

Comment: @Demetris added as well!